# Elegant Dotenv Preloading w/ package.json knex scripts

Tags: node.js, docker, knex.js, npm-scripts, dotenv

I am trying to find a more elegant way to preload my dotenv variables when running knex commands in my package.json scripts.

I was able to find a working solution [here](https://github.com/knex/knex/issues/2624) but it seems more convoluted than it needs to be and want to understand either why this is needed or if there is a better way to accomplish the same thing.

[CODEBASE - 100% docker](https://github.com/WIL-what-i-learned/ExpressValidators)

---

Here are my `package.json` scripts

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node index.js",
    "dev:watch": "nodemon index.js",

    "migrate:make": "node -r dotenv/config ./node_modules/knex/bin/cli.js migrate:make --knexfile database/knexfile.js",
    "migrate": "node -r dotenv/config ./node_modules/knex/bin/cli.js migrate:latest --knexfile database/knexfile.js",
    "migrate:rollback": "node -r dotenv/config ./node_modules/knex/bin/cli.js migrate:rollback --knexfile database/knexfile.js",
    
    "seed:make": "node -r dotenv/config ./node_modules/knex/bin/cli.js seed:make --knexfile database/knexfile.js",
    "seed": "node -r dotenv/config ./node_modules/knex/bin/cli.js seed:run --knexfile database/knexfile.js"
  },
```

**What I don't understand is why the `./node_modules/knex/bin/cli.js` is needed** because none of the knex scripts work without it.

---

**Relevant Files**

database > knexfile

```
require('dotenv').config();
module.exports = {
    local: {
        client: 'postgres',
        connection: {
            host: 'db',
            user: process.env.PRODUCTION_POSTGRES_USER,
            password: process.env.PRODUCTION_POSTGRES_PASSWORD,
            database: process.env.PRODUCTION_POSTGRES_DB
        },
        migrations: {
            directory: __dirname + '/migrations',
        },
        seeds: {
            directory: __dirname + '/seeds',
        }
    },
    testing: {
        client: 'postgres',
        connection: {
            host: 'db_test',
            user: process.env.TEST_POSTGRES_USER,
            password: process.env.TEST_POSTGRES_PASSWORD,
            database: process.env.TEST_POSTGRES_DB
        },
        migrations: {
            directory: __dirname + '/migrations',
        },
        seeds: {
            directory: __dirname + '/seeds',
        }
    }
}
```

database > index.js

```
require('dotenv').config();
const knex = require('knex')
const knex_config = require('./knexfile')

module.exports = knex(knex_config[process.env.NODE_ENV])
```